# two images in HTML one is loading and the other one is not

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="logos">
  <a href="http://twitter.com"> <img scr="twitter-logo.png"widht=50 alt="twitter logo"</a>
  <a href="http://facebook.com"> <img src="facebook-logo.png"width=50 alt="facebok logo"</a>
</div
```

the twitter logo is not working but the facebook one is. Ive tried everything i could think of. Please help!!!

Comment: The width for twitter is misspelt. src too, the closing div it isn't closed.

Comment: try on your website to load the twitter logo by url directly znd see if that works

Comment: scr, widht? What is taht?

Comment: `src` and `width` typo errors

Comment: there are so many mistakes in those 4 lines that it is obvious you didn't pay any attention to it and came here right away. Please review your code before coming here, or you'll be opening new questions all day long...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because you misspelt `src` in your Twitter line

Answer (score 1):

Clean up your code. `widht` and `scr` is wrong.

Closing div is missing '>'

Add quotes for the attribute values. add a space between each attributes. space missing after `scr="twitter-logo.png"`

Answer (score 1):

To prevent further issues like that in the future the W3C validator can be helpfull:

[W3C Online Validation Tool](https://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code hopefully it will be working perfectly

```
<div class="logos">
  <a href="http://twitter.com"> <img src="twitter-logo.png"widht=50 alt="twitter logo"</a>
  <a href="http://facebook.com"> <img src="facebook-logo.png"width=50 alt="facebok logo"</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @MamounBenghezal some code was missing in the answer, due to incorrect formatting ; it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, fixed your "widht" to "width" too :)

```
<div class="logos">
<a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="twitter-logo.png" width=50 alt="twitter logo"></a> 
<a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="facebook-logo.png" width=50 alt="facebok logo"></a> 
</div>
```